# embeddable navigation engine for windows mobile

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, windows-mobile, compact-framework, navigation

I've been working on an order management system for some time, about 1.5 years. It's written in .NET so I use .NET Compact Framework 3.5. All this time I tried different brands and versions of navigation software. In Windows Mobile (both Windows CE and Mobile) I had some problems managing 2 softwares, our application and the navigation software. For a desktop solution it's easy to implement some mapping software to your solution, like MapInfo's ActiveX or a custom control working with Google Maps, Bing Maps, etc...

For any mobile version, I never found a navigation software which can provide a User Control which can be added to your own application, so you won't have to deal with 2 seperate processes.

So has anyone tried or remember a Windows Mobile solution like an ActiveX control or something?

Answer (score 0):

I've used Bing Maas under the Compact Framework without any problem and without any "second app".  It's not an Active X control, but [they have a Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980922.aspx) that is pretty simple to consume that provides map images as well as turn-by-turn directions.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm aware of Bing Maps. It can be a solution but it would be slow and costy since my application will be running in different countries so roaming costs and quality of data connection can be a problem. What I meant was a complete navigation solution (example: Map&Guide Fleet Navigator), with offline maps, voice directions and etc...

By the way thanks for OpenNetCF, I use it for our projects.